# Callback from Facebook with OmniAuth gives strange url hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

The callback from facebook is appending #*=* to my root url redirect.

I have read that this is a known issue, but I'm using omniauth and not sure how to fix it when using that gem.

How can I get a clean redirect back to my root_url?

Comment: Callback from Google with OmniAuth gives this hash too